# VersionRevision always 0 in Assembly version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, assemblyversions

Since we don't have any access to the pipeline and just using git because of restrictions, I thought of having the versioning this way:

> 1..<month&day>. e.g. 1.22.1026.903

Problem is the VersionRevision always return 0

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
        <VersionMinor>$([System.Int64]::Parse($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date.ToString("yy"))))</VersionMinor>
        <VersionPatch Condition="'$(VersionPatch)' == ''">$([System.Int64]::Parse($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date.ToString("MMdd"))))</VersionPatch>
        <VersionRevision Condition="'$(VersionRevision)' == ''">$([System.Int64]::Parse($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date.ToString("HHmm"))))</VersionRevision>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <Version>$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).$(VersionPatch).$(VersionRevision)</Version>
        <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>-->
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Tested static with leading zeroes and it was fine.

```
<VersionRevision Condition="'$(VersionRevision)' == ''">$([System.Int64]::Parse("0903"))
```

Comment: Is there any reason you've tagged with with asp.net-core? I'd expect the project type to be irrelevant.

Comment: Just remove the `Date` otherwise you ignore the time in the day part and it's always 0

Comment: @radoslawik: I suggest posting that as an answer. I'd personally get rid of the `Int64.Parse` part as well - the property is a string, so why parse and then implicitly reformat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Date` property returns a new `DateTime` with the same date, but the time is set to 00:00:00 thus the VersionRevision is `0000`.  So removing `Date` should solve the problem.

Also, as mentioned in the comment to the question, the `Int64.Parse` is redundant.